# Error in attempting to create a new Stack project with GHCJS compiler

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghcjs

I am attempting to set up a new Stack project on NixOS with GHCJS as the compiler following the instructions at http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/ghcjs.html

I have included in my stack.yaml file the following lines of code (all on one line because tab spaces seem to give issues):

```
# Compiler specifying the GHCJS compiler for this project (using improved base).
compiler: ghcjs-0.2.0.20151230.3_ghc-7.10.2
compiler-check: match-exact
setup-info: 
    ghcjs: source: 
        ghcjs-0.2.0.20151230.3_ghc7.10.2: 
            url: "https://github.com/nrolland/ghcjs/releases/download/v.0.2.0.20151230.3/ghcjs-0.2.0.20151230.3.tar.gz"
```

and I have retrieved the following error message when I ran `stack setup`

```
Could not parse '/home/lorkaan/pandocJS/stack.yaml':
InvalidYaml (Just (YamlParseException {yamlProblem = "mapping values are not allowed in this context", yamlContext = "", yamlProblemMark = YamlMark {yamlIndex = 487, yamlLine = 12, yamlColumn = 17}}))
See https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/release/doc/yaml_configuration.md.
```

Additionally, I tried removing the `setup-info` field because Stack was complaining about it, leaving my `stack.yaml` file like:

```
# Compiler specifying the GHCJS compiler for this project (using improved base).
compiler: ghcjs-0.2.0.20151230.3_ghc-7.10.2
compiler-check: match-exact
```

which produces this output with the stack setup command:

```
Warning: /home/lorkaan/pandocJS/stack.yaml: Unrecognized field in ProjectAndConfigMonoid: compiler
Preparing to install GHC to an isolated location.
This will not interfere with any system-level installation.
Already downloaded.                 
The following executables are missing and must be installed: make
```

Does anybody have any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 4):

1. the first error is because of a basic syntax error in your YAML configuration. The correct version would be:

```
setup-info: 
    ghcjs:
        source: 
            ghcjs-0.2.0.20151230.3_ghc7.10.2: 
                url: "https://github.com/nrolland/ghcjs/releases/download/v.0.2.0.20151230.3/ghcjs-0.2.0.20151230.3.tar.gz"
```

2. The second error is because of exactly what it says: you are lacking the `make` utility. You need to use your Linux distribution's package management system to install `make`. Since I don't know which distribution you are on, I can only recommend simply executing the `$ make` command and seeing if the environment is smart enough to point out which package it can be found in. Ubuntu typically does that. Then it's only a matter of `apt-get install`-ing the package, or possibly `yum install`-ing on e.g. CentOS and Fedora, etc.

*P.S. questions like yours normally get a downvote for not having shown sufficient effort in diagnosing the problem (or for putting 2 totally separate problems under a single question) but I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt and just hoping you'll be tidier next time.*